# Why is Identity.IsAuthenticated() sometimes true sometimes false

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have an MVC application which uses an Authentication service, with IsAuthenticated() method which returns true/false.

It doesn't seem to be connected to the FormsAuthentication.SignOut() method or when I add a new Authorisation cookie on login.

Sign in:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket)));
```

Sign out:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

I have a custom authorise attribute on my controller which calls the auth service with IsAuthenticated() but it is returning the wrong value.

Does anyone know why the following code would sometimes return true or false?

```
userPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copied from comment above)

My authentication service has a dependency on IPrincipal which is injected by StructureMap during startup. However, at that point it will be unauthenticated. I need to use the IPrincipal off the current thread. This is passed into AuthorizeCore() which is being called on my CustomAuthorise class (inherits from AuthorizeAttribute)

Answer (score 2):

the `IsAuthenticated` always return false if you call it from non secure page and have set requireSSL="true" on web config, because can not read the authenticated cookie.

In the other cases is return true if the user is authenticated and false if not. Set an assert like this one to check that you ask it from secure pages.

```
Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection, "oops, the IsAuthenticated is not working here");

if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{

}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have SSL set-up. IsAuthenticated returns false when it is called from the service on AuthorizeCore() which is my custom Authorize attribute.

Comment: @Jon then maybe can not read the cookies and the session. Do you have setup the service to read write cookies and session data ?

Comment: I think I might have realised the problem. My authentication service has a dependency on IPrincipal which is injected by StructureMap during startup. However, at that point it will be unauthenticated. I need to use the IPrincipal off the current thread. This is passed into AuthorizeCore() which is being called on my CustomAuthorise class (inherits from AuthorizeAttribute).